# mercurial error http 500 access denied

Tags: mercurial

When I try to push my recent commits to my remote server I get a `mercurial error http 500 access denied` error message.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mercurial error http 500 access denied
```

This can be caused by access problems on the server you want to push to. On my server I accidentaly created the mercurial repo with `root` owner and group.

I just changed the owner and group of the server side repo with 
`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data MyRepo/`
 and I was able to push again.

Comment: This is usually the issue.  If you can browse and pull, but not push, it's because the web server doesn't have permission to write to those files.